# Grid system - gap between rows & columns doesn't work when I add inner input in same size

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Grid system - gap between rows & columns doesn't work when I add inner input in same size.

When I create grid system and add some gap between them and inside add input with

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

it take all entire size without gap size
it should be smaller and don't take extra size from gap

```css
.formOuter > .form {
  padding: 12px 25% 10px 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "grid-1 grid-2" "grid-3 grid-3" "grid-4 grid-4";
  grid-gap: 6px;
}

.formOuter > .form > .grid-1,
.formOuter > .form > .grid-2,
.formOuter > .form > .grid-3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.formOuter > .form > label > input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-1 {
  grid-area: grid-1;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-2 {
  grid-area: grid-2;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-3 {
  grid-area: grid-3;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-4 {
  grid-area: grid-4;
}
```

```html
      <div class="formOuter">

        <div class="form">

          <label class="grid-1">
            <input type="text">
          </label>

          <label class="grid-2">
            <input type="text">
          </label>

          <label class="grid-3">
            <input type="text">
          </label>

          <input type="submit" class="grid-4">

        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the default `input` rules - `padding: 1px 2px;`. Right here:

```
input[type="text" i] {
    padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

I overridden this rule by setting the value to 0 - `padding: 0;` And also, in order to include the values of the margins and borders of the width and height of the `input`, I added `box-sizing: border-box;`.

As a result, the problem was solved with two lines of css rules (for the selector `.formOuter > .form > label > input`):

```
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

```css
.formOuter > .form {
  padding: 12px 25% 10px 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "grid-1 grid-2" "grid-3 grid-3" "grid-4 grid-4";
  grid-gap: 6px;
}

.formOuter > .form > .grid-1,
.formOuter > .form > .grid-2,
.formOuter > .form > .grid-3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.formOuter > .form > label > input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-1 {
  grid-area: grid-1;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-2 {
  grid-area: grid-2;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-3 {
  grid-area: grid-3;
}

.formOuter>.form>.grid-4 {
  grid-area: grid-4;
}
```

```html
<div class="formOuter">

        <div class="form">

          <label class="grid-1">
            <input type="text">
          </label>

          <label class="grid-2">
            <input type="text">
          </label>

          <label class="grid-3">
            <input type="text">
          </label>

          <input type="submit" class="grid-4">

        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand why we need flexbox I already use grid system

Comment: @Lolix, it is normal practice to use grid and flex together.

Comment: @Lolix, I made a second example without flex. Grid only.

Comment: but why you use again grid \flex on top I already create a grid template

Comment: in the second example flex is absent. only the grid is used. please look carefully.

Comment: I saw it , i don't understand why do you need to use grid two time one on .formOuter > .form and second on .formOuter > .form > .grid-1 etc.. , if I create grid on father 'formOuter > .form' i have template so why add a new position.

Comment: i get this bug because grid-template-areas? if I use another way for grid it work without two grid templates?

Comment: I looked at your example again and understood what the problem is. Now I will make you a normal decision and explain what the problem was.

Comment: Check out my new answer.